# firebase database only work when read write is set to true

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created firebase database and connected it to my android app. But it only writes when `read` and `write` is set to `true` in security rules. It gives warning that `security rules are public`. How to resolve this? I think it should work when rule are set to `false` as I have connected my app to firebase in console using `google-services.json` file but it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to add auth conditions for that.

Comment: Only authenticated users can access/write data
{
 “rules”: {
 “.read”: “auth != null”,
 “.write”: “auth != null”
 }
}

Comment: if this solve your query let me know ill post it as answer.

Comment: ok. so you are saying if a user is signed up he aill be able to use database even if rules in security are set to false?

Comment: If you set  { “rules”: { “.read”: “auth != null”, “.write”: “auth != null” } } like this then only signed up user can access data.

Comment: You just cannot set it as false, if your willing that your user can use database for read write.

Comment: alright i'll check. have you worked with phone auth? i have some issues there too

Comment: Yeah context me at ahmi.bajwa8282@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rules according to your need like this only **authenticated users** can `access/write` data

```
    { 
    “rules”: 
        { 
         “.read”: “auth != null”,
         “.write”: “auth != null” 
        } 
    }
```